# C# Razor Page disable all /Index Route for Folders?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

Hello currently I'm playing with Razor Page and wanted to ask, if there is a possibility to actually do not allow accessing the Index Page directly.

I.e. I have multiple Folders:

- Document
- Search

now I want to allow people to access them via `/Search` and `/Document`, but if anybody calls `/Search/Index` directly, he should be defaulted, to the "default" 404 handler, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom [Page route action convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#page-route-action-conventions). A convention allows you to customise the routes that apply to a page at either the page, area or folder level. To customise the routing for *all* pages, you can use a folder of `/`. Here's an example of how you can remove the `Index` routes:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
        {
            var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;

            // Go down in reverse order to simplify removing from a list that's being iterated.
            for (var i = selectorCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var selectorTemplate = model.Selectors[i].AttributeRouteModel.Template;

                if (selectorTemplate.EndsWith("Index")) // Perhaps be more specific here.
                    model.Selectors.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        });
    });
```

Note that for the Index page at the root, the selector to remove is `Index` (not `/Index`), whereas for your others it is `Page/Index`. I've kept it simple in the example, but this will also remove any Pages that have `Index` as part of their name (it's unlikely this will matter, but it's worth mentioning).

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm, sadly if I have a index route with a parameter, it won't work with just EndsWith, so I need to hardcode these views :/